# Woocommerce - Mudar a classe de transporte se um campo estiver preenchido no checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugin-wordpress

Estou querendo mudar a classe de impostos (ou zerar os impostos) de uma compra caso certo campo estiver preenchido no checkout, que seria a Inscrição Estadual, se a empresa ou pessoa física tiver inscrição estadual não pagará certo imposto, então irá zerar. Tentei de algumas maneiras e sem sucesso.

Uma das coisas que tentei fazer foi fazer um woocommerce_product_tax_class:

```
$checkout = WC()->checkout();
$billing_ie = $checkout->get_value( 'billing_ie' );

if ($billing_ie == '') {
    $tax_class = 'Zero Rate';
}
else {
    $tax_class = 'ICMS';
}

return $tax_class;
```

Se alguém conhecer algum plugin para nova regra de ICMS estadual do Brasil também me ajuda, pois é isso que estou fazendo.